# Linux, Debian Shell dont remove directory

Tags: linux, shell, debian

i have one problem,I do my shell script and don't remove **dir**, if i put *cmd* on *console* we remove but on shell don't. It would be appreciated if anybody can help me? I do chmod 777 on file and same.. only cmd remove don't work.

## my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#screen -S 4388.MG-SW-IceLand -X stuff "stop^M"
echo "stop the server"
sleep 2;
echo "remove all"
rm -rf /home/minecraft/minigames/SkyWars/IceLand/world/
sleep 5;
echo "un_tar"
tar -xfv /home/minecraft/minigames/SkyWars/IceLand/world.tar.gz
sleep 10;
echo "start server"
#screen -S 4388.MG-SW-IceLand -X stuff "java -jar -Xmx1G sp1.7.5.jar^M"
```

**i do cat -A resetserver.sh and say:**

```
#!/bin/bash^M$
#screen -S 4388.MG-SW-IceLand -X stuff "stop^M"^M$
echo "stop the server"^M$
sleep 2;^M$
echo "remove all"^M$
rm -rf /home/minecraft/minigames/SkyWars/IceLand/world/^M$
sleep 5;^M$
echo "untar"^M$
tar -xfv /home/minecraft/minigames/SkyWars/IceLand/world.tar.gz^M$
sleep 10;^M$
echo "start server"^M$
#screen -S 4388.MG-SW-IceLand -X stuff "java -jar -Xmx1G sp1.7.5.jar^M
```

Now i have another problem, on execute on putty all work, but on execut whit javaplugin remove dir but dont tar, some help?

thanks for help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Windows` carriage-return character `^M` which is screwing up your script by doing.

```
dos2unix resetserver.sh
```

Or using `sed`,

```
sed -i s/^M$//g resetserver.sh
```

Comment: now on tar say: tar: /home/minecraft/minigames/SkyWars/IceLand/world.tar.gz\r: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @tg95: Happy to help!

Comment: Now i have another problem, on execute on putty all work, but on execut whit javaplugin remove dir but dont tar, some help?

Comment: @tg95: This is totally different question, beyond the scope of the current question. Can you post it as a separate one with your problems?